# Missing Piece of Pie - Can you find it?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence, letter-sequence

> **A piece is missing!**

What should it be?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hint 1

> - 5 is diagonal to G, where G is the next letter of F(the first Letter of 5);

Hint 2

> - 3 is diagonal to U, where U is the next letter of T(the first Letter of 3);

Hint 3

> - 1 is diagonal to P, where P is the next letter of O(the first Letter of 1);

Answer

> - Therefore answer is **T** because it is the next letter of S(the first Letter of 7);

Comment: Mathematics tag, "pie" in the title, presented as a circle, with the numbers 3 and 1 inside... and the correct answer has nothing to do with π? I'm shocked! :P

Comment: @jafe I was too! I actually found a way to get $\pi$ from it, but alas was incorrect lol

Answer (score 5):

I've exhausted my mental state on this one today; my only plausible guess is:

> $4$

Because:

> If you convert the letters to their respective numerical placements in the alphabet:
>  $G = 7$
>  $P = 16$
>  $U = 21$
>  You can use the digits we have $[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]$ to create $\pi$ with some math:
>  $31415$ is the most obvious. But let's keep going:
>  $7 + 2 = 9$ so we now have $314159$ which leaves $[1, 6, 7]$.
>  Knowing the next digit is $2$, we can use our remaining digits to get there: $7 - 6 + 1 = 2$ so we get $3141592$ which is $\pi$ accurate to $6$ decimal places without the decimal point.

Comment: @PerpethualJ - I'm sorry, that was not correct. You put forth a great amount of effort, and if this was a real contest, I'd give you the prize because you stayed in the ring like "Rocky Balboa" and never gave up. The solution, ironically, was much, much simpler than the road you went down. Check above, I marked it correct. Thanks for playing!

Answer (score 3):

Half serious answer:

> `M` or `|\/|`

Because

> In LeetSpeek (13375P33K):
>  
>  G17 == GIT == GET
>  5UM == SUM == SOME
>  P13 == PIE
>  
>  The only thing missing is the letter "M" which AFAIK doesn't have a numerical analogue. (Although this explanation is suspicious because "G" then should have been either "6" or "9", rather than the letter)

Comment: I am sorry, @V , that's not it. The solution is much less complicated. Don't look too deep.

Comment: Heh, I thought so. Still, worth a try. :)

Comment: This is my favorite answer anyone submitted to any of my puzzles.

Comment: @JohnS. YAY! ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> T

Because:

> Like @Lonewolf 's answer, take the opposite piece's number's first letter ("S"even), then take the next letter alphabetically. I believe he incorrectly took the *previous* letter of R

EDIT:
@Lonewolf corrected his at the same time I posted this!

Comment: You got it Kugo2006, nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> I believe it's the letter "**R**"

Because:

> Kind of like what @lonewolf said but
>  it's the letter before the one that is diagonal. Where "R" is one
>  letter before "S" which the word "Seven" begins with and "P" is across
>  from "1" which is one letter after "O" which the word "One begins with
>  and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

> T

Same reason as @Lonewolf

Except:

> P comes after O in One, all of the letters are the letter after the first letter of the number

Edit:
@kugo2006 posted his answer at the same time I was typing and I didn't notice 'til now that Lonewolf also corrected his

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> B

Because:

> 1 - 3 : Difference 2 
>  5 - 7 : Difference 2 
>  U - P : Difference 5 
>  G - B : Difference 5

...if that makes any since!

Comment: please hide your answers.